# Pytest does not run with python3

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

My pytest installation with ubuntu is not running with python3 instead it uses python 2.7

How am able to switch to python3 when running pytest?

python3 -m pytest . is working, but it is not an option, because the program, that runs my tests uses pytest ...

Comment: In this case you have to make sure that your program has the correct PATH set, so that it finds the correct pytest or Python version.

Comment: should not pytest have the right python?

Comment: pytest does not have Python, it uses the Python it finds in the path.

Comment: i set an alias python=python, but it did not help

Comment: You could call ``python3-pytest`` with ``pytest-3``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used pytest-3 to solve this problem.